# manifest.json v3 add jquery-3.6.1.min.js

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, manifest.json

hi I am wondering if this is correct usage in manifest.json using v3 ??
trying to apply to all urls and add jquery

{

```
"name": "Bulk Image Downloader",
"description": "Download every image on the web page",
"version": "0.1",
"action": {
    "default_popup": "popup/index.html"
},
"background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js",
    "js":"jquery-3.6.1.min.js"
  },
"content_scripts": [{
    "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
    "js": ["content.js","jquery-3.6.1.min.js"]
}],
"manifest_version": 3,
"host_permissions": ["*://*/*"]
```

}

Comment: No, you can't use jquery in a service worker and you don't need it. Use `fetch`.